# upload file to the network mapped drive in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am using c# asp.net mvc 3 and entity framework to upload the file to the network drive mapped as Z drive. I have following c# code for determining file path:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Z:/upload/catone/", fileName);
aries.SaveAs(path);
```

I am using window server 2008 and IIS 7. I have also check Security of upload folder of network drive and have acess full control for EVERYONE user. If I changed file path to local drive, it works fine. But it shows following error while uploading to network drive (Z:/).

```
Could not find a part of the path 
'Z:\upload\catone\_2013011504265221N_todaily.wav'.
```

Comment: can u open Z:\ in your windows explorer?

Comment: yes I can open z:\ in windows explorer

Comment: when you are using Path.Combine what about adding Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/upload/catone/"),filename);

Comment: You really should use the appropriate path delimiter \ for your OS.

Comment: Mapped network drives are user specific. Z:\ for you may not be for the user account under which your web site is running. Hence it does not recogonize z:\

Comment: `Your path will look like @"\\ComputerName\PublicShare\folder\"...etc`

Comment: `Make sure the app is run by a user that is allowed to go to that drive (not anonymous) and has read write permissions. Make sure the user you created on both machines have same password and username.`

Answer (score 4):

Your code is running under IIS and thus is run with access privileges of the IIS user account which may not have access to that network drive.

You can try runnning the app pool under your identity for instance, to rule this issue out, or give full access to the group IIS_IUSRS to that folder.

Comment: I have done same as you have said. But I am not able to add permission  to IIS_IUSRS. When I add that user under security option of folder and give full control access. It shows in Group or username but when I click apply or Ok button, It disapper from that list of Group. What is happening, What might be problem.

Comment: @CodeManiac - That may be because you yourself don't have rights to give rights on that remote folder. Try the other approach, impersonate.

Answer (score 1):

First of all save the file in local machine , 
than after use file.copy(Source, Destination, true) method to save file in network drive.

try that it is helpful for you